Estimate height of tennis ball from single camera
I'm working on tennis recordings and trying to estimate height of the ball.
What I have:

images of tennis courts w/ identification of lines and ball
therefore I can calculate camera_matrix, distortion_coefficients and homography

Now let's assume that the ball goes from A(x, y, 0) to B(x', y', 0). This is not realistic since balls aren't shot from the ground ie. actual z>0 but nevermind.
I define a new basis (A, u, v) with u=AB being the ground position of the ball and v acting as a z dimension (see figure 1)

It is interesting to not that the ball trajectory in the new coordinate system (A, u, v) describes a parabola (reaching max height at the middle of [AB]).

Then I'm tempted to use the second coordinates as the actual height of the ball but then I have several problem.

I have intuition about this basis change but I'm not sure how to justify mathematically that the second coordinate in A(u, v) correspond to the actual z coordinate in the real world. (the intuition is that the ball ground coordinate (i.e. projection of real world ball into the ground plane) MUST follow AB (assuming to spin or wind) SO whatever moves from AB is another dimension that is not x nor y therefore z.

the image is undistorted so court lines appears straight (instead of curvy initially) thanks to camera calibration steps. However, calilbration and homography is done for a plane=the tennis court=points with (z=0) so the image is actually curved along the z axis, therefore, depending on where A is located on the court, vector v would differ see figure 3.

How can I "undistort" the Z axis or calculate a Z vector for each point of the plane?




from a single view, you can't. you need multiple cameras.

Actually, they can, with more or less accuracy depending on camera resolution, shutter time and frame rate: it's a tennis ball, size is known to within 1cm or better..

You can try, under some simplifying assumptions that may or may not apply depending on your camera hardware.
Your camera is intrinsically calibrated, and the diameter of a "nominal" (regulation) tennis ball is known. Let's assume you can disregard motion blur (i.e., the shutter speed is near instantaneous compared to the ball's velocity) and/or that the camera does not have a rolling shutter. Then a single frame is an image of the ball at one point in time. You can model the ball as a point in motion (its center), and approximate the image of that point with the center of mass of the image of the ball. You can then segment the ball's image and compute its apparent area (count its pixels, and remember to remove lens distortion before computing it), then its radius. You can then estimate the ball's center's location in 3D space as the point on the ray through the image of the center, at a distance equal to d = f R/r, where f is the focal length in pixels, R is the radius of the ball in m, and r the computed radius of the image of the ball in pixels. This way you get a (noisy) 3D point in camera coordinates for each image frame, which you can then transform into world coordinates after having separately estimated the camera location and pose from the image of the tennis court's rectangle.
Iterating over the frames yields a sequence of points in 3D space. You can then directly compute the distance of each point from the court's plane. Last, you can try to improve your estimates fitting the points to a motion model that takes into account air resistance (which for a tennis ball is definitely nontrivial). However, if you are, say, only interested in the ball's maximum elevation, you can ignore the air resistance in a small neighborhood of the maximum (say, 3 or 5 frames), and just fit a parabola.
It may be very hard to make the above work with accuracy sufficient for an application. In practice, as others have suggested, it may be simpler and more accurate to use multiple synchronized cameras in a stereo configuration.
